# Analytic Signal vs Baseband Signal

Tags: analytic-signal, baseband

I am wondering if a baseband signal, which is can be defined as $s_{BB}(t) = I + jQ$, is at the same time an analytic signal. In my understanding, analytic signals are defined as $s^+(t) = s(t) + jH(s(t))$, where $H(s(t))$ is the hilbert transform of $s$.
So optically the formula for the baseband and analytic signal look very similar. The difference is, that the analytic signal does not have negative frequencies, whereas the baseband signal has negative frequencies.
So in my understanding, a baseband signal is not an analytical signal. Is that correct?

Another related question that I have: I have read in a book that it is possible to send an analytic signal via 2 cables to a different location. This is like sending an IQ baseband signal somewhere which is modulated to a higher frequency. I have never seen an application where this is done (probably because I only deal with digital transmission systems). I think it would always make more sense to send the IQ baseband signal across the wire, because it uses lower frequencies. But maybe there are applications that I am not aware of?

**Edit:** I have found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal#Complex_envelope.2Fbaseband
it says "This function goes by various names, such as complex envelope and complex baseband." So I guess that answers the first part of my question with "yes, a downconverted analytic signal is called complex envelope or complex baseband"